# JPA Repository :Delete a row from database using native query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

I want to delete a record on the basis of userId But when I run this code and execute following query it gives me an error on 404 
Please Help How can I delete Data?

**PropertyReport.java**

```
@Entity 
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"reportedProperty", "reporter"})
    })
public class PropertyReport implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Property.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="reportedProperty")
    private Property property;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="reporter")
    private User user;

    @Column(length=1024)
    private String Report;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Property getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(Property property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getReport() {
        return Report;
    }

    public void setReport(String report) {
        Report = report;
    }
}
```

**PropertyReportReppository.java**

```
public interface PropertyReportRepository extends JpaRepository<PropertyReport, Long>{
@Modifying
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('allRights')")
    @Query("delete from  PropertyReport pr where pr.user.id=:userId")
    int deleteTenantReview(@Param ("userId") Long userId); }
```

API which I called

**API :** http://localhost:8555/api/propertyReports/search/removeByUserId/2

Comment: Show your code of controller layer.

Comment: Controller Layer? @Forward

Comment: Why 404? I think it's not about db, it's about url mapping.

Comment: A 404 error has nothing to do with JPA. It's an error from your web server indicating that the URL you're trying to access is not mapped to any resource.

Comment: I also don't know why 404 that's why I am asking

Comment: @JBNizet Am I calling right API ?

Comment: Usually the URL `http://localhost:8555/api/propertyReports/search/removeByUserId/2` is mapped to a @Controller class that extracts the parameters from the URL you gave and invokes your repository to execute the query. When your server can find no resource mapped to that URL, it returns a 404 error.

Comment: Thankyou All :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your url maping is as below-

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

  @RequestMapping("/api/propertyReports/search/removeByUse‌​rId/{userId}")
  public String hello(@PathVariable(value = "userId") final Long userId){

//add method call here to delete your data that you want
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

for more detail how to create url mapping [click here](http://www.jhaji.in/2016/02/how-to-start-with-boot-scratch-step-1.html)